# Unable to update a lookup field despite appearing in the debug log

Tags: apex

I have a lookup field that is not updating for some odd reason. I can see the field being set in the debug log with the proper value, but the actual field is not being updated

```
(11:46:48.0 (105304277)|USER_DEBUG|[116]|DEBUG|The line item product: a0R1N00000CLyRcUAL).
```

I have added a simplified/untested version of the code. Can you please help?

```
public class myExample_TriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {
    public myExample_TriggerHandler (){
    }   
    public override void beforeupdate(){ 
       updateProdu();
    }                       
    public Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();

    public void updateProdu(){    
      for(Line_Item__c li : (List<Line_Item__c)Trigger.New) {    
        if(li.Category__c != null) {
                idSet.add(li.Id);     
        }                                                                                                 
      }                                                                                                                                                                     

      List<Line_Item__c> liLst = [SELECT Id,Name,Category__c,Product__c FROM Line_Item__c where id in : idSet]

      for(Line_Item__c li : (List<Line_Item__c>)Trigger.New) {             
       for(Line_Item__c l : liLst){
         if(liLst.size()> 0){                                                                                                                        
              if(l.Category__c == 'Just a test'){              
                l.Product__c = 'a0R1N00000CLyRcUAL'; //harcoded temporarily                                
              }
                system.debug('The line item product: ' + l.Product__c );
         }                                                                                                                                                               
       }              
     }                               
   }

}
```

Comment: How are you calling this handler from the trigger body? Is it a `before` trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update records in the Trigger Context (Trigger.new), also i got rid of the pointless .size() check, being in the for body should be proof enough that the list size > 0.

```
public void updateProdu()
{                                                                                                                                                                         
  for(Line_Item__c li : (List<Line_Item__c>)Trigger.New) {             
        if(li.Category__c == 'Just a test') {              
          li.Product__c = 'a0R1N00000CLyRcUAL'; //harcoded temporarily                                
        }
        system.debug('The line item product: ' + l.Product__c );                                                                                                                                                              
    }              
}
```

Comment: This guided me in the right direction and now the field is updating even with the complete and more complex logic that doesn't use the hardcoded value - "Update records in the Trigger Context (Trigger.new)," Not sure how I missed that one, but I did. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, but if I might make another suggestion I would pass in a list to a static method that the trigger calls. Using Trigger.new in a method makes testing reliant on a trigger being used. Test your trigger and its handlers separate

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are trying to implicitly update a field in a record that is NOT in the trigger context (i.e. `liList`)

```
List<Line_Item__c> liLst = [SELECT Id,Name,Category__c,Product__c FROM Line_Item__c where id in : idSet]
```

....

```
   for(Line_Item__c l : liLst){
         if(liLst.size()> 0){                                                                                                                        
              if(l.Category__c == 'Just a test'){              
                l.Product__c = 'a0R1N00000CLyRcUAL'; //harcoded temporarily                                
              }
                system.debug('The line item product: ' + l.Product__c );
         }
```

Only the records in list `liList` will be implicitly updated in a before Trigger context. All other records (those not in Trigger context) must be updated by DML

Answer (score 0):

The value of `Product__c` is not getting updated because you are not updating the instance which is in context, instead you are querying the same records again from database and updating it in memory without firing an update statement to database.

As you are trying to update the same record in `before update` event, there is no need to query those records again, you can directly update the records in context and it won't need an update statement as well.

Your code should be

```
for(Line_Item__c li : (List<Line_Item__c>)Trigger.New) {
    if(li.Category__c == 'Just a test'){ 
        li.Product__c = 'a0R1N00000CLyRcUAL'; //harcoded temporarily 
    } 
    system.debug('The line item product: ' + li.Product__c );          
}
```